How to trigger a cloud function only once on a collection that writes same document twice?
I just implemented push notifications on a chat app and its triggering the notification twice because of the way the messages are stored.
Collection is,
Messages/userID/receiverID/messageID
Messages/receiverID/UserID/messageID
When a user sends a message, it is stored in the users collection as well as the receivers collection.
The function to trigger a push notification triggers when ever a message is created in the messageID location, as of now it triggers twice as the message is stored twice. Is there a mechanism in Firestore to handle something like this and only trigger the function once? or is there an additional feature that handles this type of situation?
Tried to trigger a cloud function to send a push notification when a document is created but it gets triggered twice because of the way the document is duplicated when stored.
Cloud function,
  exports.messageNotificationsTrigger = functions
    .region('europe-west2') 
    .firestore
    .document('/messages/{toUid}/{fromUid}/{id}')
    .onCreate(async (snap, context) => {
      const db = admin.firestore();
      const data = snap.data();
      const message = data.text;
      const toId = data.toId;
      const fromId = data.fromId;
      const fromUserName = data.fromUserName;
      const userReference = db.collection("tokens").doc(`${toId}`);
      const userToSend = await userReference.get();

      if (!userToSend.exists) {
        functions.logger.error("No such user", toId);
        return;
      } else {
        const userData = userToSend.data();
        const token = userData?.notificationToken;

        // Notification payload
        const payload = {

          notification: {
            title: fromUserName,
            body: message,
          },   
          data : {
            "mutable-content": "1"
            
             }

        };


Won't the sender already have the app open? So why would you want to trigger on the sender's documents? Why not only trigger on the receiver collection? Doing that would give you a unique path to trigger on. --- Keep in mind that we can't see how you currently implemented the trigger. So if there's a mistake in there, we can't help you spot it. Therefor it's best if you also add a minimal repro to the question.

@FrankvanPuffelen The problem with that is maybe because of wildcards on the sending and receiving user IDs that would cause them to both match the function.

It's not possible to stop a function from triggering at least once for each matching event that would trigger it.
You might want to consider insetad:

A different implementation where there is only one collection for a document for all messages that should trigger the function. And, if absolutely required, perhaps other documents in other collections (maybe one for each user) that don't trigger anything at all.

Writing some logic in the function that attempts to figure out which of the two document triggers should actually perform the resulting action (instead of allowing either one of them could perform it).



Even if I add some logic in to trigger the resulting action once, the function would still trigger twice. Is creating another collection the only solution in your opinion?

Having a function trigger and do nothing is not necessarily a bad thing.  But if you only want one thing to trigger, the only write one document with a matching trigger. There are no workarounds to that.

I guess I could add a another collection Messages/receiverID/UserID/messageID/Trigger/ and store an additional document once, and trigger the function on this location, still additional saves
